# LaTeX barely loading on math.stackexchange on my PC

Tags: bug, mathjax

I'm not the first to report a problem like this, but I couldn't find any recent complaints about this from the past few years.

Lately, LaTeX symbols have not been loading *very* slowly for me on math.stackexchange.com. They can take up to a few minutes to load. I've read that this can have something to do with LaTeX loading on https, when it's meant for http, but I have no idea how to fix that. I already tried deleting my browser history, but that didn't help.

I'm using Windows 11, and my browser is Chrome. Both have the latest updates.

Comment: That sounds more like an internet issue. Are you able to load other websites normally?

Comment: Can you try with other browsers and other devices? Have you tried to disable all browser extensions (e.g. LocalCDN)?

Comment: @Accelerator I'm connected to Ethernet, and other sites work perfectly. I hopped on a Discord call soon after writing this post, and I was able to screen share and stream YouTube videos.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Disabling all browser extensions helped a lot! Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the issue was a Chrome browser extension. Do you happen to know which extension caused the issue?

Comment: I have been having this issue, as well, but it is not limited to the Chrome browser